# how to Load test a java api (Jar) using modern tools?

Tags: java, testing, jar, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a simple java code integrated with Apache Camel which also uses camel-kafka component for logging messages in kafka topics. I have created a class which handles single request. 
Using threads I can create various threads to invoke above class method to log messages.

Currently I need to load test this JAR using a tool. I want to know a tool that have very low learning curve.

Load test:

- increasing users to allow multiple messages to be logged concurrently
- variation of messages to increase/decrease message size
- Time taken by specific users to log specific messages.

I have gone through

- JMeter (learning curve is big)
- JProfiler (it does not load test but monitors the application if I am
  not wrong)
- Netbeans Load generator (again it uses JMeter)

Comment: just my 2cents: If the learning curve of JMeter is too steep for you you might have difficulty in finding an appropriate tool.

Comment: i am looking for any tool that involves few hours of spending and can load test quickly as its a simple jar obviously learning is not an issue but spending days to fully learn is currently not possible.

Comment: Did you search for an example how to loadtest custom code with JMeter ? And for some hints how to setup a loadtest effectively ? The latter can be found in the blog of blazemeter for example and where to put a jar of your code and have JMeter loadtest it can be found here: http://doloadtest.blogspot.de/2013/04/using-custom-java-class-in-jmeter.html

Comment: yeah, started on JMeter java samplers and junit requests. Thanks for that but again any quick utility like we have SOAPUI for testing web-services(REST/SOAP) and quickly do load-testing. looking for such quick utility for JAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download [groovy-all-*.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all) and drop it to /lib folder of your JMeter installation
2. Restart JMeter
3. Add [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to test plan. Set desired amount of virtual users, interations and/or duration.
4. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) as a child of the thread group
5. Choose "groovy" in the "language" dropdown
6. Put your "simple java code" in JSR223 Sampler's "Script" area
7. Save test plan.
8. Run it.

Was that so hard?

Comment: well, not hard once you have grip over the tool, obviously you have and you are helping others. That worked and minimized my work too. Another thing is what if i want to include large files as content in my object String ? i have to do it programmatically or JMeter have such options ?

Comment: I included my JARs in JMETER_HOME/lib folder but i had to provide fully package name to access the classes e.g: com.foo.className to write script code.